# How can I send Cookies with Guzzlehttp/guzzle 6?

Tags: php, cookies, request, guzzle, get-request

I need to send a request with custom cookies.

I have tried to set cookieJar like this:

```
$cookieJar = CookieJar::fromArray(array($cookieName=>$cookieStr),
                    'api.mobra.in');

                $res = $this->guzzleClient->request($requestMethod, $url,
                    [
                        'cookies' => [$cookieJar]
                    ]
                );
```

But it is getting an error

> cookies must be an instance of GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJarInterface

Please suggest example or explain in details.
I gone through documents but they have not mentioned in detail.

Thank you!

Comment: I've tried GuzzleHttp\Cookie\SetCookie.  Maybe is wrong.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
use GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar;

$cookieJar = CookieJar::fromArray([
    'cookie_name' => 'cookie_value'
], 'example.com');

$client->request('GET', '/get', ['cookies' => $cookieJar]);
```

You can read the documentation [here](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html?highlight=cookie#cookies).

Comment: Note: the domain for the cookie jar _has_ to match the domain you are requesting against.

Comment: i was reading that part of the documentation inside out and upside down, I couldnt find a way to set a cookie, it only mentioned misleading "cookie jar interface".... never a part of the article that looked like your suggestion.  You can send us a screenshot of it to, because I can send a screenshot of the "cookies" section it never mentioned anything like this, otherwise I wouldnt have to google this one out.

Comment: With guzzle the best documentation is the source code.

Comment: I tried out using cookieJar but getting error like 
cookies must be an instance of GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJarInterface

Answer (score 8):

One more way to add a cookie to the request with Guzzle:

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com';
$request_options = [
  'headers' => ['Cookie' => 'COOKIE_NAME=VALUE']
];
$response = $this->httpClient->request('GET', $url, $request_options);
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me when compared to the cookie jar.

Answer (score 2):

**Guzzle** can maintain a cookie session for you if instructed using the cookies request option. When sending a request, the cookies option must be set to an instance of `GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJarInterface`.

```
// Use a specific cookie jar
$jar = new \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar;
$r = $client->request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org/cookies', [
    'cookies' => $jar
]);
```

You can set cookies to true in a client constructor if you would like to use a shared cookie jar for all requests.

```
// Use a shared client cookie jar
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['cookies' => true]);
$r = $client->request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org/cookies');
```

Check too the full [quickstart](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html).

Comment: Yea, that part of documentation says nothing about how to set custom cookie.

Answer (score 2):

For **sending cookie with Guzzle Http in laravel** you can use this sample code:

```
        //your address
        $address = "http://example.com/xyz";
        
        //your cookie
        $coockie = ['Cookie' => "Key=Value"];
        
        //your request
        $res = Http::withOptions([
            'headers' => $coockie
        ])->get($address);
```